# MongoDB Rest API doesn't allow me to search "deeper" using query parameters

Tags: html, mongodb, rest, url

I currently have a few documents inside my MongoDB database that have this template:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5616b757e4b0d2d408b39097"
    },
    "username": "admin",
    "hash": "encrypted",
    "salt": "salt",
    "mail": "mail@mail.com",
    "answered": {
        "x": 203,
        "y": 102
    }
}
```

I want to search this using the REST api like this:

> https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/[REDACTED]/collections/users?q={"username":"admin"}&f={"answered":**1**}&apiKey=[REDACTED]

this correctly gives me

```
[ { "answered" : { "x" : 203 , "y" : 102 } } ]
```

Which is fine, but I want to search deeper into the "answered" field, like this:

> https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/[REDACTED]/collections/users?q={"username":"admin"}&f={"answered":**{x:1}**}&apiKey=[REDACTED]

But this will give an error, I tried several variations but they don't work and the [documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/data-api/#list-documents) doesn't say how it should be formatted in the URL.

What I would ultimately want is this:

```
[ { "answered" : { "x" : 203 } } ]
```

Comment: Try `{"answered.x": 1}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{"answered.x": 1}`

According to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/):

> **Equality Match on Fields within an Embedded Document**
>
> Use the dot
>   notation to match by specific fields in an embedded document. Equality
>   matches for specific fields in an embedded document will select
>   documents in the collection where the embedded document contains the
>   specified fields with the specified values. The embedded document can
>   contain additional fields.
>
> In the following example, the query uses the dot notation to match all
>   documents where the value of the field producer is an embedded
>   document that contains a field company with the value 'ABC123' and may
>   contain other fields:
>
> `db.inventory.find( { 'producer.company': 'ABC123' } )`

Comment: Thank you, I searched around in there but it seems I didn't search for long enough, tested and it works.

Comment: Awesome! Please accept answer to close the question if that solves your problem :)  (You may have to wait a min time since it has been pretty quick. Idr.)